# Slate JS not support Mobile Keypad voice support feature

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor, slatejs

I'm encountering an issue with voice typing in my ReactJS application using the Stale component for text editing, deployed on both web and mobile apps through the Ionic Capacitor framework.

Problem:
When attempting to use the voice typing feature on Android/iOS keypads with the Stale component, typing automatically stops. While the keyboard remains open, voice typing is interrupted. Interestingly, this issue is not observed with other HTML text fields or Material-UI text fields.

Why does this issue occur exclusively with the Stale component?

Are there any known compatibility issues between the Stale component and voice typing features on mobile devices?

Can anyone suggest a solution please?